# Slide-out menu not working, NetBeans keeps displaying a syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a slide-out menu but netbeans keeps saying the syntax is not right.

console displays: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined[Meer info]  navbar.js:16:1

The above file is in a menu php file which I have included on every page.

I am unable to find where the error is located.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".fa-times" ).click(funtion(){
        $(".sidebar_menu").addClass("hide_menu");
        $(".toggle_menu").addClass("opacity_one");
        
            });    
            $(".toggle_menu").click(funtion(){
        $(".sidebar_menu").removeClass("hide_menu");
        $(".toggle_menu").removeClass("opacity_one");
                
            });
});
```

```css
/* menu 2 */
.toggle_menu{
    position:fixed;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 15px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    color:white;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:#648b79;
    z-index:1000000;
    font-size:2em;
    opacity:0;
}
.sidebar_menu{
    position:fixed;
    width:250px;
    margin-left:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100vh;
    max-height:100vh;
    background-color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.9);
    opacity:0.9;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;    
}
.fa-times{
    right:10px;
    top:10px;
    opacity:0.7;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:absolute;
    color:white;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;      
}
.fa-times:hover{
    opacity:1;
}
.boxed_item{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid 2px white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 22px;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:70px;    
}
.logo_bold{
    font-weight: 800;
}
.logo_title{
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
.navigation_selection{
    margin: 20px 0;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.navigation_item{
    font-weight: 200;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color:white;
    padding: 12px 0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-size: 14px;
    color:#D8D8D8;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #d8d8d8;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.boxed_item_smaller{
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#D8D8D8;
    width:200px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
cursor: pointer;
border-width:1px;
margin:0 0 20px 0;
}
.boxed_item_smaller:hover{
background-color:white;
color:#111;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.hide_menu{
    margin-left:-250px;
}
.opacity_one{
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="scriptsm.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<i class="fa fa-bars toggle_menu"></i>
    <div class="sidebar_menu">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
   <center>
    <a href="#"><h1 class="boxed_item">robby<span class="logo_bold">test</span></h1></a>
    <h2 class="logo_title">test</h2>
   </center>
        
        <ul class="navigation_selection">
            <li class="navigation_item"> ? </li>
            <li class="navigation_item"> ? </li>
            <li class="navigation_item"> ? </li>
            <li class="navigation_item"> ? </li>
            <li class="navigation_item"> ? </li>
            <li class="navigation_item"> ? </li>
        </ul>
   <center>
    <a href="#"><h1 class="boxed_item boxed_item_smaller">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>??</h1></a>
   </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html is invalid thats is why jquery is not loaded.

you are missing > after the src attribute in the script tag

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"</script>
```

it should be

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

the second issue is wrong spelling of function in the click events. It should be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fa-times").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar_menu").addClass("hide_menu");
    $(".toggle_menu").addClass("opacity_one");

  });
  $(".toggle_menu").click(function() {
    $(".sidebar_menu").removeClass("hide_menu");
    $(".toggle_menu").removeClass("opacity_one");
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks that must have been from the copy pasting , but it is still  not working.

Comment: @RobbyMorales check the update. click event function was miss spelled. after this correction it will work perfectly.